# How to read for X seconds maximum in C++?

Tags: c++, timeout, file-descriptor

I want my program to wait for something to read in a FIFO, but if the `read` (I use `std::fstream`) lasts more than 5 seconds, I want it to exit.

Is it possible or do I have to use `alarm` absolutely?

Thank you.

Comment: Is read() able to be safely interrupted?

Comment: I doubt it's possible in pure standard library C++ for starters. System reads should allow timeouting reads, though (yeah, I don't like that idea too).

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I have a `mutex` to unlock unfortunately, I think that may be a problem...

Comment: @TNW Which system reads are you talking about? Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe there is a clean portable way to do this. Your best option you may to use `poll` on Linux or `WaitForSingleObject` on WinAPI and provide a timeout there.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I was thinking about using `select` with a `struct timeval` maybe?

Comment: AFAIK `select` only works on sockets and not regular file handles in windows . Use `WaitForSingleObject` on windows and `poll` or `select` on *nix based systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a clean way to accomplish this that is portable C++ only solution. Your best option is to use `poll` or `select` on *nix based systems and `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` on Windows.

You can do this transparently by creating a proxy `streambuffer` class that forwards calls to a real `streambuffer` object. This will allow you to call the appropriate `wait` function before doing the actual read. It might look something like this...

```
class MyStreamBuffer : public std::basic_streambuf<char>
{
public:
    MyStreamBuffer(std::fstream& streamBuffer, int timeoutValue)
        : timeoutValue_(timeoutvalue),
          streamBuffer_(streamBuffer)
    {
    }

protected:
    virtual std::streamsize xsgetn( char_type* s, std::streamsize count )
    {
        if(!wait(timeoutValue_))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return streamBuffer_.xsgetn(s, count);
     }

private:
     bool wait() const
     {
         // Not entirely complete but you get the idea
         return (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(...));
     }

    const int       timeoutValue_;
    std::fstream&   streamBuffer_;
};
```

You would need to do this on every call through. It might get a little tedious but would provide a transparent solution for providing timeouts even where they might not be explicitly supported in client code.

Comment: Thanks, I went through it with select and it was easier to implement than what I thought about at first (I don't need it to be cross-platforms so it is okay)

Answer (score 0):

For the one insterested by the way I resolved my problem, here is my function reading from my stream. I couldn't finally use `std::fstream` so I replaced it by `C` system calls.

```
std::string
NamedPipe::readForSeconds(int seconds)
{
    fd_set              readfs;
    struct timeval      t = { seconds, 0 };

    FD_ZERO(&readfs);
    FD_SET(this->_stream, &readfs);

    if (select(this->_stream + 1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &t) < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid select");
    if (FD_ISSET(this->_stream, &readfs))
        return this->read();
    throw NamedPipe::timeoutException();
}
```